# Not Producing correct output when used like operator - sql server 2008

Tags: sql, t-sql

**My SQL SERVER IS CASE SENSITIVE: Latin1_General_CI_AS**

I have 2 table as given below.

```
DECLARE @TABLEA TABLE
(
CUSTNAME VARCHAR (100)
)

INSERT @TABLEA

SELECT 'ONE STOP MOTORIST CENTRE'


DECLARE @TABLEB TABLE
(
CUSTNAME VARCHAR (100)
)

INSERT @TABLEB

SELECT 'ONE STOP MOTORIST CENTRE & BODYSHOP' UNION ALL
SELECT 'One Stop Motorist Centre (Cambridge' UNION ALL
SELECT 'One Stop Motorist Centre (Cambridge' UNION ALL
SELECT 'One Stop Motorist Centre & Bodyshop'
```

but i am not getting when i am running below query, it is not giving any result.

```
SELECT * FROM @TABLEA A INNER JOIN @TABLEB B ON  '%'+ UPPER(A.[CUSTNAME])+'%' like '%'+ UPPER(B.[CUSTNAME])+'%'
```

Can anyone suggest what tweek i have to do to get the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern goes on the *right* side of `like`.  For your example:

```
SELECT *
FROM @TABLEA A INNER JOIN
     @TABLEB B
     ON UPPER(B.[CUSTNAME]) LIKE '%'+ UPPER(A.[CUSTNAME])+'%';
```

If you want inclusion in either direction, then use two conditions:

```
SELECT *
FROM @TABLEA A INNER JOIN
     @TABLEB B
     ON UPPER(B.[CUSTNAME]) LIKE '%'+ UPPER(A.[CUSTNAME])+'%' OR
        UPPER(A.[CUSTNAME]) LIKE '%'+ UPPER(B.[CUSTNAME])+'%';
```

I should also note that by default, SQL Server is case-insensitive.  You don't need to upper-case the values in most cases.